# No Entity Framework provider found for the ADO.net while passing string to constructor

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Im trying to pass my connection string directly to the constructor of my dbcontext.

```cs
"data source=xxx;initial catalog=testDb;integrated security=True;trustservercertificate=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework\" providerName=\"System.Data.SqlClient"
```

but I'm getting following error

> Exception thrown: 'System.InvalidOperationException' in EntityFramework.dll
> An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll but was not handled in user code
> No Entity Framework provider found for the ADO.NET provider with invariant name 'System.Data.SqlClient'. Make sure the provider is registered in the 'entityFramework' section of the application config file. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=260882 for more information.

The reason why I need to pass it directly is because problematic situation with my configuration which is stored in registry of environment instead of app.config.

I've tried different approaches with EntityconnectionStringBuilder or even getting data directly from file generated from EF:

```cs
string connectionString = customConfig.ConnectionStrings.ConnectionStrings["connecitonString"]?.ConnectionString;
```

but no luck.

Comment: Just copy the xml configuration from the documentation at the link.